# Fully automated theme install and activation via a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, themes

I've managed to get my "semi noob proof" site installer plugin 98% complete, but I'm having a slight issue with the theme activation. The plugin is able to copy the theme into the themes directory fine. However, my switch_theme statement that attempts to set it to the active theme is missing something.

I'm using...

```
function activate_theme(){
switch_theme('my_theme', 'style.css');
}
```

...as a trigger statement inside the plugin to activate the newly uploaded theme (its uploaded as part of a function that processes further up in the code from the "activate_theme()" function. My theme, in this instance is called 'my_theme' and that's what I'm using in the theme's style.css

I can tell that the switch theme is partially working, since when I click on "Appearance", the default 2010 theme is no longer the active theme, however, the "my_theme" theme is not set to active either. Its as if the process only partially completed and neither 2010 nor my theme are fully activated. So, I still have to manually click "Activate" to finish the process.

What could I be missing?

Comment: since switch_theme() is located in wp-includes/theme.php, maybe you can debug it (by debugger, or by echoing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you must also set the options `template` and `stylesheet`, thats all.
I use this via filter to set a theme for testing or on a category, post-type and so on. But you must change the fields in table options for active the theme ready.

I hope this help, i dont tested - only my idea.

Comment: You are spot on. I actually figured this out and forgot to update the question. So I'm upvoting and selecting your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Here is my function:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/302650/29133

```
/*
 * For directory structure like:
 * 
 * /your-plugin/
 * - /your-plugin.php
 * - /themes/
 * - - /yourthemename/
 *
 * 
 */
```

Add to the `your-plugin.php` file:

```php
function updateTheme($theme){
    update_option('template', $theme);
    update_option('stylesheet', $theme);
    update_option('current_theme', $theme);
}

add_action( 'setup_theme', 'change_theme' );

function change_theme(){

 //Replace with your own conditional
 $enable_theme = true; // Forcing true;


  if($enable_theme == true):

    register_theme_directory( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'themes' );
    $theme = "yourthemename";

  else:

    $theme = "default";

  endif;

    updateTheme($theme);
}
```